# How to split a string into multiple hash keys in perl

Tags: perl, split, hashmap

I have a series of strings for example

```
my @strings;
$strings[1] = 'foo/bar/some/more';
$strings[2] = 'also/some/stuff';
$strings[3] = 'this/can/have/way/too/many/substrings';
```

What I would like to do is to split these strings and store them in a hash as keys like this

```
my %hash;
$hash{foo}{bar}{some}{more} = 1;
$hash{also}{some}{stuff} = 1;
$hash{this}{can}{have}{way}{too}{many}{substrings} = 1;
```

I could go on and list my failed attempts, but I don't think they add to the value to the question, but I will mention one. Lets say I converted `'foo/bar/some/more'` to `'{foo}{bar}{some}{more}'`. Could I somehow store that in a variable and do something like the following?

```
my $var = '{foo}{bar}{some}{more}';
$hash$var = 1;
```

NOTE: THIS DOESN'T WORK, but I hope it only doesn't due to a syntax error.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Identical logic to Shawn's answer. But I've hidden the clever hash-walking bit in a subroutine. And I've set the final value to 1 rather than an empty hash reference.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @keys = qw(
  foo/bar/some/more
  also/some/stuff
  this/can/have/way/too/many/substrings
);

my %hash;

for (@keys) {
  multilevel(\%hash, $_);
}

say Dumper \%hash;

sub multilevel {
  my ($hashref, $string) = @_;

  my $curr_ref = $hashref;
  my @strings = split m[/], $string;
  for (@strings[0 .. $#strings - 1]) {
    $curr_ref->{$_} //= {};
    $curr_ref = $curr_ref->{$_};
  }

  $curr_ref->{@strings[-1]} = 1;
}
```

Comment: I just tried this with the following data, and I don't think it's working like one would hope.  `my @keys = qw(
  foo/bar/some/more
  also/some/stuff
  also/bar/baz
  this/can/have/way/too/many/substrings
);`  Specifically, the second `also` stomps on the first.

Comment: @ErikBennett: Yes, I thought of that bug over the weekend, but got distracted before I could fix it. Thanks for reminding me. I've fixed it now (I changed `$curr_ref->{$_} = {}` to `$curr_ref->{$_} //= {}`).

Comment: How would one make it work for `
my @keys = qw(
  foo/bar/some/more
  also/some/stuff
  also/bar/baz
  also/bar
  this/can/have/way/too/many/substrings
);
`
?

Comment: It already works for that situation as far as it can ever work. You've run into a logical limitation of Perl hashes. It is impossible for `$hash{also}{bar}` to simultaneously contain both `1` and a reference to another sub-hash.

Comment: That makes sense.  I was thinking of a situation like ( usr usr/local usr/local/bin ).  So, where is the `//=` operator documented?  I can't find it in perldocs, and my new book is in the mail.  Mine is 5.006, or something.  Thanks.

Comment: `//=` is the assignment version of `//`. So `$x //= %y` is a short way of writing `$x = $x // $y`. And `//` is the "defined-or" operator. It's like `||` but it checks its left-hand operand for "definedness", not truth. So it's really `$x = defined $x ? $x : $y`. The operator was [introduced in 5.10.0](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl5100delta.pod#Defined-or-operator). And, as an operator, it's documented in [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or).

Answer (score 4):

You have to use hash references to walk down thru the list of keys.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = ();

while( my $string = <DATA> ){
    chomp $string;
    my @keys = split /\//, $string;
    my $hash_ref = \%hash;
    for my $key ( @keys ){
        $hash_ref->{$key} = {};
        $hash_ref = $hash_ref->{$key};
    }
}
say Dumper \%hash;

__DATA__
foo/bar/some/more
also/some/stuff
this/can/have/way/too/many/substrings
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a library.

```
use Data::Diver qw(DiveVal);
my @strings = (
    undef,
    'foo/bar/some/more',
    'also/some/stuff',
    'this/can/have/way/too/many/substrings',
);
my %hash;
for my $index (1..3) {
    my $root = {};
    DiveVal($root, split '/', $strings[$index]) = 1;
    %hash = (%hash, %$root);
}
__END__
(
    also => {some => {stuff => 1}},
    foo  => {bar => {some => {more => 1}}},
    this => {can => {have => {way => {too => {many => {substrings => 1}}}}}},
)
```

Comment: Looks good, I sadly don't have that library, and I will rather go with the other solutions, than install a new library.

Answer (score 0):

I took the easy way out w/'eval':

```
use Data::Dumper;

%hash = ();
@strings = ( 'this/is/a/path', 'and/another/path', 'and/one/final/path' );
foreach ( @strings ) {
    s/\//\}\{/g;
    $str = '{' . $_ . '}';      # version 2: remove this line, and then
    eval( "\$hash$str = 1;" );  #   eval( "\$hash{$_} = 1;" );
}

print Dumper( %hash )."\n";
```

Comment: Please always use `strict` and `warnings` in any code you post here. And I suggest, that you use `print Dumper(\%hash );` instead of `print Dumper( %hash )."\n";`, it is clearer.